# Connect Power Query to Share Point excel file

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have connected power query to an excel file located in a share point folder.  I used the get data from web function in excel and entered the URL For the excel file.  This worked great.  My issue is, the report name is currently "Datasheet July 2019".  Next month this file is overwritten and renamed "Datasheet - August 2019".  Is there a way to enter a wild card in the URL to pull back the file regardless of the month year at the end? "Datasheet" will never change as the beginning of the file name.  There is only one file named "Datasheet...." in the folder.

current url:
http://bi-sites.com/sites/Monthly_Reports%20Datasheet%20-%20July%202019.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities here.

You could use the current month and plug it into the file name like this

```
varDate = Date.MonthName(DateTime.LocalNow()) & "%20" & Number.ToText(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow())),
varFile = "http://bi-sites.com/sites/Monthly_Reports%20Datasheet%20-" & varDate &".xlsx"
```

Then edit the Source to use `varFile` instead of the path you posted.

Or, you could create a query from folder and filter the result to leave only the files with the .xlsx extension and the name "contains" `Datasheet`.